# Is it possible to run four monitors using a dual head AGP card and a dual head PCI card?

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, pci, agp

This question isn't concerning the latest technology. It asks about hardware from around 2001-2003.

I have a dual head Radeon 9800 AGP card running two monitors. I have a dual head PCI Radeon 9200. Would installing it enable four monitor support in Windows XP?  Does Catalyst need settings configured in it for this to work?

Is it possible to run four monitors using a dual head  AGP card and a dual head PCI card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The version of Catalyst would need to be known to confirm it's supported (but it certainly should be), but not a big issue to update that anyway...